# Make autowireup = true the defaul

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I normally write in c#. I did a demo in c# and when I create a new .aspx page it defaults to autowireup = true. I started a new job and they write in VB.net. When I create a new aspx page autowireup defauts to false, How / where do I set that to default to true? Im using VS 2013

Comment: Open aspx page and change the `AutoEventWireup` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the value to `true` in the `web.config` file as:

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
  <pages autoEventWireup="true" />
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

The above, will, of course apply to all pages the `web.config` file is associated with.

However if you want to change the value to a particular page then you will need to add the `AutoEventWireup` attribute to the `@` Page directive, as:

```
<% @Page AutoEventWireup="true" %>
```

Comment: Doesnot work. After I do what you suggest and I add a new aspx file it still defaults to autowireup=false, but thanks for the effort

Comment: Have you tried restarting your IDE to see if it makes a difference?

Comment: Yes Izzy, I restarted the IDE and I also tried an aspx page with and without a master page

Comment: Have you checked machine.config

Comment: As @Developer mentioned check the `machine.config` and see if `autoEventWireup` is set to false. If it is, that means it will affect all ASP.NET Web Forms on the computer.